# Which works best to describe character, item or dungeon properties: Affix or Trait?

Tags: game-mechanics, terminology

I am working on an RPG portion of my game called "**The Underground King**".

My item generator uses the same properties that also apply to characters, vehicles and racing levels (dungeons for short).

I am torn between using the term "Affix" and the term "Trait" to describe the procedurally generated properties, mainly because English is not my first language, and there may be a clear difference in usage between the two.

Examples of traits:
**Hearty**: For items, it gives 5 more HP, for characters they have 5 more HP, for vehicles they have 5 more durability, for dungeons, enemies have 5 HP each.
**Indomitable**: For items, characters and vehicles, it gives the player the ability to ressurect at 100% hp, once dead. For the dungeon, dead enemies remain invulnerable for a few seconds after being dead.

I am open to either opinions or arguments for any of them. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a native English speaker, Trait sounds much more accurate in this case. Affix is much less used and so harder to understand. Calling them traits makes it clear that they are properties of the item. Other options could be Property, or Modifier, but Trait still sounds best in my opinion. "Affix" sounds like something you learn in school and never worry about again, whereas Trait is in everyday use in ways similar to your system.

Comment: I am not a native English speaker, but I know the word trait, and have used it alot. I have never heard the word Affix though

Answer (score 1):

I would agree with trait or modifier if you are listing it below the name.
It should be called prefix if you list it before the name and suffix if it is after the name

Hearty ring, Shield of indomitably -> Affix description

Discipol's robe

- Hearty
- Indomitable

A trait or modifier of the robe`